# longtable is unnecessarily pushed to the next page

Tags: tables, spacing, pdftex, longtable, verbatim

The second longtable is unnecessarily pushed to the next page:

[image: pages]

I have tried to make it into a minimal example as much as possible:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

Some line of text

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}l@{}}
\toprule
header \\
\midrule
\endhead
value \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\vspace*{97mm}

\begin{Highlighting}[]
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
\end{Highlighting}

\begin{Highlighting}[]
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
\end{Highlighting}

Another line of text

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}l@{}}
\toprule
header \\
\midrule
\endhead
value \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can add a \newpage or \needspace{2\baselineskip} before "Another line of text."  Evidently longtable thinks it is at the bottom of page 1 rather than the top of page 2.

Comment: Putting `\needspace{\baselineskip}` after "Another line of text." also works (needspace package).

Comment: No, longtable starts formatting before page 1 is completed.  There is enough room to put the paragraph "Another line of text." on page one, but for some reason it gets moved to page 2.  You don't have to put \needspace before **every** longtable, but OTOH it doesn't hurt.  I imagine @davidcarlisle will provide a bug fix in the next release.

Comment: You can also put `\pagebreak[3]` after "Another line of text", but now the break occurs after rather than before.

Comment: The longtable tag should have already caught his attention.  The important thing is that you can patch it now and not have to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this issue was a bug and has been fixed somewhere between release `LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4` and `LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1`.

See: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/604